# How to initate full uncompression of ZFS filesystem

Tags: zfs

I have created a large filesystem with compression on. Now I have disabled compression, but I don't get full performance. The reason is that uncompression is lazy and will only apply to new files.

Is there a way to initiate uncompression on background?

I know about copying files to a new partition and back, but is there a smarter way?

Answer (score 1):

That's odd as usually, a better performance is observed with compression enabled.

Anyway, should you really want to decompress your files, there is no need to use a new "partition" (not sure if you mean a new file-system or pool here). Assuming there is enough space to hold a copy of the biggest file in your file system, and that the files are not being concurrently use/updated by applications, you can just copy the files in the same directory then move them to their original name, overwriting the compressed original, eg:

```
find . -type f -exec ksh -c 'for i do echo cp -p "$i" "$i.u$$" && echo mv "$i.u$$" "$i"; done' ksh {} +
```

Remove *both* "echo" instructions to actually do the change.

Comment: I am trying to do the same, but via send/receive like desribed here http://www.mail-archive.com/zfs-discuss@opensolaris.org/msg28616.html. Hopefully that helps. I have thought of doing something like you suggest, I will try that next if no luck

Comment: The zfs-discuss solution is better than mine as it handles snapshots and put the file system in read-only. One drawback is it requires much more free disk space.